# How to type a input ref for file upload

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to type the ref for the input, but not sure how. I'm using it for file upload. Any idea on how I can type this?

```
const ProfileLayout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

  let inputUpdateAvatarPhoto = useRef();

.
.
.
.

 const handleImageChange = async (e: any) => {
   const formData = new FormData();
        
   formData.append('avatar', inputUpdateAvatarPhoto.files[0]);
    
.
.
.
.

    <input
      id="avatar"
      accept="image/*"
      type="file"
      ref={input => (inputUpdateAvatarPhoto = input)}
      onInput={e => {
      handleImageChange(e);
      }}
    />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null).  And you just pass the created ref to the input ref property rather than using a callback. ref={inputUpdateAvatarPhoto}

Comment: I still get "Property 'files' does not exist on type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'."

Comment: That error means you are looking at inputUpdateAvatarPhoto.files but you want to be looking at inputUpdateAvatarPhoto.current?.files.  You are mixing up the various methods of using refs (very common issue).

Comment: useRef creates a ref object where the actual value is stored on the .current property.

Comment: how i get the file now? https://pasteboard.co/JRP4Pi1.jpg
I really suck at  ts lol

Comment: Ok so the files property might not be set (might be null or undefined) so you want to use an if statement to check that you have files before doing anything with them.  But I’m not sure if FileList is assignable to string | Blob so there might still be an issue.  I’m on my phone but I can check this out on my computer in a few hours.

Comment: Looks like you might need to iterate over it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: ok i will check it out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Fixing Your Ref

Your ref has a number of issues:

- You need to declare the type of your ref by setting the generic on `useRef` like `useRef<HTMLInputElement>`.
- React expects the initial value for a DOM element ref to be `null` instead of `undefined`.
- You are mixing up [ref object syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) with [callback ref syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).  With a ref object you just pass the whole object to the DOM element like `ref={inputUpdateAvatarPhoto}`
- In order to access the current value of the ref object, you need to look at the `.current` property

This code should work, but the next code is better

```
const ProfileLayoutV1: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const inputUpdateAvatarPhoto = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const handleImageChange = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const files = inputUpdateAvatarPhoto.current?.files;
    // make sure that it's not null or undefined
    if (files) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("avatar", files[0]);
    }
    // need to set something
  };

  return (
    <input
      id="avatar"
      accept="image/*"
      type="file"
      ref={inputUpdateAvatarPhoto}
      onInput={(e) => {
        handleImageChange(e);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

#### You Don't Need a Ref

See how your `handleImageChange` function gets an event `e`, but doesn't use it?  `inputUpdateAvatarPhoto.current` is the same as `e.currentTarget`!

We actually don't even need a handler on the `input` though, because you can get a `FormData` object for the whole form!  Check out this example in the MDN docs: [Sending files using a FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object).

We want to set the `name` property on the `input` since that's what's used to determine its key in the `FormData` object.

```
const ProfileLayoutV2: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // prevent the page from redirecting ot reloading
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the `FormData` for the whole form
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
    // logs a `File` object
    console.log(formData.get("avatar"));
  };

  return (
    <form name="profile_form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        id="avatar"
        name="avatar"
        accept="image/*"
        type="file"
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Note that if you want to use the `File` directly, you'll need to check that it's defined.

```
const avatar = formData.get("avatar"); // type is `string | File | null`
if ( avatar instanceof File ) {
  console.log("we have a file", avatar); // type is now just `File`
}
```